# Abortable: Dangling Futures?

Tags: rust, async-await, rust-tokio

I am using the [Abortable](https://docs.rs/futures/latest/futures/future/struct.Abortable.html) crate to suspend the execution of a Future. Say I have an abortable future in which the async function itself awaits other async functions. My question is, if I abort the root Future, would the child Futures be aborted instantly at the same time, or would they be dangling?

I read the source code for [Abortable](https://docs.rs/futures-util/0.3.25/src/futures_util/abortable.rs.html#181), in particular the code for `try_poll`:

```
fn try_poll<I>(
        mut self: Pin<&mut Self>,
        cx: &mut Context<'_>,
        poll: impl Fn(Pin<&mut T>, &mut Context<'_>) -> Poll<I>,
    ) -> Poll<Result<I, Aborted>> {
        // Check if the task has been aborted
        if self.is_aborted() {
            return Poll::Ready(Err(Aborted));
        }

        // attempt to complete the task
        if let Poll::Ready(x) = poll(self.as_mut().project().task, cx) {
            return Poll::Ready(Ok(x));
        }

        // Register to receive a wakeup if the task is aborted in the future
        self.inner.waker.register(cx.waker());

        // Check to see if the task was aborted between the first check and
        // registration.
        // Checking with `is_aborted` which uses `Relaxed` is sufficient because
        // `register` introduces an `AcqRel` barrier.
        if self.is_aborted() {
            return Poll::Ready(Err(Aborted));
        }

        Poll::Pending
    }
```

My understanding is that once `abort` is called, it will propagate to the downstream Futures in the sense that when the root Future is aborted, it will stop polling its child Future (because `Poll::Ready(Err(Aborted))` will be returned), which will in turn stop polling its child. If this reasoning is true, then the effect of calling abort is immediate.
Another argument is that if Future is pull-based, the root node should be invoked first and then propagate to the sub tasks until the leaf one is invoked and aborted (and then go back to root). This means that there is a latency between when the `abort` method is called and when the leaf Future actually stops polling. Might be relevant, but this [blogpost](https://blog.yoshuawuyts.com/async-cancellation-1/#propagating-cancellation-for-futures) mentions dangling tasks, and I am concerned this is the case.
For example, here is a toy example that I wrote:

```
use futures::future::{AbortHandle, Abortable};
use tokio::{time::sleep};
use std::{time::{Duration, SystemTime}};

/*
 *       main
 *         \
 *       child
 *         | \
 *        |   \
 *    leaf1   leaf2
 */
 

async fn leaf2() {
    println!("This will not be printed")
}

async fn leaf1(s: String) {
    println!("[{:?}] ====== in a ======", SystemTime::now());
    for i in 0..100000 {
        println!("[{:?}] before sleep i is {}", SystemTime::now(), i);
        sleep(Duration::from_millis(1)).await;
        println!("[{:?}] {}! i is {}", SystemTime::now(), s.clone(), i);
    }
}
 
async fn child(s: String) {
    println!("[{:?}] ====== in child ======", SystemTime::now());
    leaf1(s.clone()).await;
    leaf2().await
}
 
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let (abort_handle, abort_registration) = AbortHandle::new_pair();
    let result_fut = Abortable::new(child(String::from("Hello")), abort_registration);

    tokio::spawn(async move {
        println!("{:?} ^^^^^ before sleep ^^^^^", SystemTime::now());
        sleep(Duration::from_millis(100)).await;
        println!("{:?} ^^^^^ after sleep, about to abort ^^^^^", SystemTime::now());
        abort_handle.abort();
        println!("{:?} ***** operation aborted *****", SystemTime::now());
    });

    println!("{:?} ====== before main sleeps ======", SystemTime::now());
    sleep(Duration::from_millis(5)).await;
    println!("{:?} ====== after main wakes up from sleep and now getting results \
            ======", SystemTime::now());
    result_fut.await.unwrap();
}
```

[Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=04706034865364aec39a427b2d3767d0)
I am personally leaning more towards the first argument that there is no latency between abortion of the root and abortion of leaf because the leaf doesn't need to know it needs to abort (the leaf only pulls when root tells it to). The example above prints the time the child is executed and the time when the root is aborted. The execution of child is always before the root is aborted, but I am not sure if this can prove that my first argument is true, so I would like to know what y'all think!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, because a future needs to polled to executed but it will not be polled if it is aborted, the child futures will not be polled either and therefore the execution will stop immediately.

Of course, execution will stop only after reaching the next yield point, and spawned tasks using `tokio::spawn()` will not stop.

Comment: Thank you! (I would've upvoted your answer if I had enough reputation points) To make sure I really understand, by "execution will stop only after reaching the next yield point", do you mean until the next time it attempts to poll the Future? (If it is already polling the child future, then the process will not be terminated immediately) My next question is, when we call `abort` on the root, how does drop happen? Does it follow a pull-based aborting chain or just root node will be aborted and other downstream futures will be dangled?

Comment: @ZHEng I meant that if for example it is currently executing `println!()`, it will not immediately stop, only when will reach a `sleep()` or something like that. I don't understand your second question.

Comment: If omit `sleep()` in the `leaf1` function, then call abort on `child`, would `child` stop polling from `leaf1` and stop printing? I guess my second question is, when abort is called, how does drop really happen? Do futures drop in a sequence (like from root to leaf, or from leaf to root, or just the root)? Do they drop at all when `abort` is called?

Comment: @ZHEng If you will remove the sleep, `child` will never yield, and thus never stop even if you abort it. Dropping the future will happen if and when the owner of the future will drop it, unrelated to the abort.

Comment: Is `sleep` the only way for `child` to yield? Any other ways?

Comment: @ZHEng Far from it. I/O, `tokio::task::yield_now()`, basically everything async that isn't CPU-intensive.

Comment: Thank you! You've been incredibly helpful!

Comment: Tasks yield whenever you call `await`.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo Not always.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I think I agree with you. When I got rid of `sleep` within the for loop of `leaf1` and awaited a simple async function that prints things instead, `child` didn't stop when I aborted it.

Answer (score 1):

1. Dropping a `Future` type equals to drop all the states within that `Future`, including its child `Future`s. Remember `Future`s in Rust are all state machines. If you succeeded in safely dropping a `Future`'s states, then it means the execution must have already been stopped before the drop, otherwise it is a data race.
2. Specifically, dropping a tokio `JoinHandle` conceptually only drops the handle itself, but does nothing about the task that the handle represents. Or in other words, if you use `tokio::spawn()`, then whatever `Future` you throw into that task became unrelated to your current `Future` (except you can receive back a result from the `JoinHandle` and explicitly call abort). So they call tokio's tasks as detached by default.
3. Let's talk about timing issues. For `Abortable`, it does not directly "drop" your `Future`. Instead, it "drops" in an indirect way. If you call `AbortHandle::abort()`, then immediately an atomic boolean flag is flipped and then a `Waker::wake()` is called, but the async executor **would be unaware of this at this moment**. The executor would still think your `Abortable` is either progressing or suspended at this moment. We should discuss them separately:

   1. The executor was still polling your `Future` at the time of the atomic boolean flip. Then according to the [source code](https://docs.rs/futures-util/0.3.26/src/futures_util/abortable.rs.html#132)

      1. If this polling happens to be the one that completes the future, then the `Abortable` would return a completion.
      2. If this polling returns `Pending` in the end, then `Abortable` has a high chance of return an aborted error, small chance of going back into suspense, depending on when the atomic flag flip became observable to the thread of this polling.

      If either a completion or an aborted error is returned, the `Abortable` as a `Future` would be considered as completed and eventually(*) get dropped. When it gets dropped, it would mean all its child `Future`s would have also been dropped.

      If you happen to be coding in a very poor style and this polling happens to have touched a long computation / a blocking call, then unfortunately, everything else would have to wait however long for this poll to return, and the executor may be starved during the process.
   2. Your `Future` was suspended at the time of the atomic boolean flip. The `Waker::wake()` call tells the executor to poll this `Abortable` at least once sometime in the future. Some time later, the executor will finally decide to give your `Abortable` a poll. Then almost immediately the poll returns an aborted error. Then the same thing happens, your `Abortable` as a `Future` would be considered as completed and eventually get dropped.

   In summary, no, the abort does not happen at the same time as the drop.

*: I'm not sure when the `Future` gets dropped after its completion. It would really depend on how Rust compiler transforms the `.await` point and I haven't looked into it yet.